# Unit Testing a @PostConstruct method in a @Startup @Singleton bean

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I start by saying that I'm at the very beginning with my adventure with java-ee and arquillian (unit testing in general).

I'm using wildfly 8.0.0CR1.

I've a class (I'm going to call this "Initialization Bean") that is a simple @Singleton `@Startup` bean with a `@PostConstruct` method that does some basic db's initialization .

It's counterpart is a unit test that inside the `@Before` method, truncates all db's tables to prepare the database for the initialization phase.

The problem is that the Initialization Bean `@PostContruct` method gets called before my unit test is set up so that the method that should truncate all database table is actually called after the Initialization Bean `@PostContruct` method.

How can I debug a `@PostContruct` method in a `@Singleton` `@Startup` bean correctly?

I hope I've been enough clear, otherwise tomorrow I'll post some real code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Did you annotate your init bean with `@javax.ejb.Singleton`?

I was experiencing the same problem, then I noticed that I annotated the init bean with `@javax.inject.Singleton`. After fixing the annotation the `@PostConstruct` method is called.

Comment: Hi @DuCh,
My problem was more about how to debug a postContruct method body using Arquillian. My `@PostConstruct` method worked fine. My problem was mainly about truncating tables before my bean got deployed into my AS-7 and then test the code. I ended up writing test unit for the code that ran inside `@PostConstruct` and a static function called from inside  `@Deployment` method that truncates all my DB Tables and then deploys the bean. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to instantiate any @StartUp classes and invoke the @PostConstruct methods before each test class. Apparently this is easily done with Spring but we are not using Spring in this environment. Here is an example of how I did it:

```
public class BaseTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void instantiateStartupClasses() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.company.project");
        //Find all classes annotated with Startup in a given package.
        Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Startup.class);
        for(Class clazz : classes) {
            if(clazz.isInterface()) continue;
            //Instantiate the object
            Object instantiatedClass = clazz.newInstance();
            //Find any PostConstruct methods on the class and invoke them using the instantiated object.
            for(Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if(method.isAnnotationPresent(PostConstruct.class)) {
                    //Invoke the post constructor method.
                    method.invoke(instantiatedClass);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is one way possible solution of the problem. You should not use Autowire for creating your bean objects with @PostConstruct method. You can create the bean through java code.

1 make in test class a method like this:

```
private BeanFactory getTestBeanFactory() {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:<your test context>-test.xml");
    return applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
}
```

2 in test do this code:

```
// get your bean object
YourBean yourBean = getTestBeanFactory().getBean(YourBean.class);
// call manually a post construct method of your bean
yourBean.<the post construct method of your bean>();
// do something with the yourBean
...
```

it`s work fine

good luck